# Get property from response

Tags: cypress

I am experimenting with cypress for api and I have an issue to get the property from the response body.

My response body:

```
[
    {
        "user_id": 1,
        "name": "Test user",
        "title": "QA",
        "active": true
    }
]
```

The property I want to assert:

```
... }).then((response)=>{
            expect(response.body).have.property('name', 'Test user')
        })
```

I think something wrong with the property I am trying to assert:('name', 'Test user').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the expect assertion correctly. Here is how you have to use it properly. I do not see any `body` in your json data. If you have `body` in your JSON, then replace `response[0]` with `response.body`

```
let response = [{
      "user_id": 1,
      "name": "Test user",
      "title": "QA",
      "active": true
    }]
expect(response[0]).to.have.property("name", "Test user");
```